# How can I show elements with only even index in a view(using Beego framework)?

Tags: go, beego

So the problem is that I can not show even elements in my view file.
I have the following code in my view file:

```
    {{range $i, $stream := .d}}
        {{if $i % 2 == 0}}
            {{$stream.Channel.Status}}
        {{end}}
    {{end}}
```

From the docs I've read that "You CANNOT use conditional expressions in if. Only boolean values are acceptable."

So how can I implement it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could always produce the filtered results back in your Go code before this executes and remove the conditional altogether.

Comment: Use `*template.Template`'s `Funcs` method to define a function that tests for even numbers and use that in your if statement.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help!